# How to get an entity via abstract MappedSuperClass by using CrudRepository findByName

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, generics, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a use case where most of my model classes have id and name as fields along with entity specific fields.

To achieve the same I have a super Class :

```
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BasicEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    public BasicEntity() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Derived Class:

```
@Entity
public class DerivedEntity extends BasicEntity {

}
```

Then I am trying to use CrudRepository to get an Entity by its name :

```
@Repository
public interface GenericRepository<T extends BasicEntity> extends CrudRepository<T, Integer> {

    //T findByName(String name);
}
```

This code gives an error

> “Not an entity: class BasicEntity".

I understand the error here , It is giving the error because class BasicEntity is not an entity individually , I want to know if there’s any way I can specify the generics to the crudRepository like T extends BaseEntity without including BasicEntity.

I also know I can use inheritance by mapping the BasicEntity class @entity & @Inheritance using concrete mapping but I don’t want that .

Is there any other way I can solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this

```
  @Entity
  @Inheritance
  public abstract class BasicEntity {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private int id;

     private String name;

    }
```

Now create one Base Repository

```
  @NoRepositoryBean
  public interface BaseRepository<T extends BasicEntity> 
  extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {

  public T findByName(String name);

  }
```

Now the other repository extends the Base Repository.

```
   public interface DevivedRepository extends BaseRepository<User> { /* ... */ }
```

**For Custom Query** 
You can Refer the correct entity in Base Repository custom query like that

```
  public interface BaseRepository 
  extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {

  @Query("select u from #{#entityName} as u where u.name = ?1 ")
  T findByName(String name);

  }
```

The value of entityName is rplacae by jpa of Type T

This will work

Comment: Adding `@NoRepositoryBean` to repository was enough for me